# How to connect hive server2 via PHP ? Is there any code available in Php?

Tags: php, hive, bigdata, syncfusion

How to connect hive database from PHP page ? I dont have idea there are some sources for Java to connect Hive via JDBC . I need Php source for connecting any bigdata platform.

Comment: Google would be a good place to start. This is not a code writing service. We're here to help you solve puzzling problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can find sources for Hive thrift client of PHP as follows.

If you are using [Syncfusion Big Data Platform](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/big-data). Make sure you have updated hive’s thrift path accordingly as mentioned in screenshots.

Native PHP Client:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-PHP

[Native PHP Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip538.png)

OR

Third Party Library:
https://github.com/Automattic/php-thrift-sql

[php-thrift-sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKAve.png)

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,
Baskaran V